# how to count the number of 1s in a subarray?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, methods

lets say I have an array of 1's and 0's like below:

`[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`

and lets say I have a subarray from it like below:

`[1, 0, 0, 1]`

how to I find the total number of 1's given any subarray (like the one above) in O(1) time?

the method constructed so that the above can happen should take O(n) time.

I thought about constructing a prefix sum of the input array (which should take O(n) time ).

So the prefix sum array for the above example is:
`[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]`

Then when given a subarray, I grab the start and end indexes of the sub array - and match it to the corresponding values in the prefix sum array and subtract the values like: `value at end index - value at start index`

so the example subarray above has the `end index: 3` and `start index 0`

if look at indexes `0` and `3` in the prefix sum array, we get the values `1` and `2` respectively.

so following the formula we do  `2 - 1` we get `1`. **So this indicates that the number of 1s in the example subarray is 1 but instead it is 2.**

so this doesn't seem to work for subarrays that contain the very first or the last element of the input array. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think, storing the sum in another array should work. Please add an example how that array would look like in your shown input and where you think it will fail.

Comment: The "prefix sum" array is good and should work. Note that the prefix sum array should have one more element than the original array.

Comment: If original array `a` is indexed from 0 to n-1, then prefix-sum array `s` should be indexed from 0 to n, with `s[k]` equal to sum of first k elements: `s[0] = 0` and  `s[k] = a[0] + ... + a[k-1]`. Then the sum of subarray `start,end` is equal to `s[end+1]-s[start]`.

Comment: @Stef it doesnt seem to work, please have a look at my edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "prefix sum" array is good and should work. Note that the prefix sum array should have one more element than the original array.

If original array `a` is indexed from 0 to n-1, then prefix-sum array `s` should be indexed from 0 to n, with `s[k]` equal to sum of first k elements: `s[0] = 0` and  `s[k] = a[0] + ... + a[k-1]`. Then the sum of subarray `start,end` is equal to `s[end+1]-s[start]`.

With your example:

```
a =    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
s = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7]

sum([1,0,0,1]) = sum(start=0,end=3) = s[3+1] - s[0] = 2 - 0 = 2.
```

Answer (score -1):

Code for Prefix Sum :

```
def create_prefix_sum_array(arr):
    prefix_sum = [0] * len(arr)
    prefix_sum[0] = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        prefix_sum[i] = prefix_sum[i - 1] + arr[i]
    return prefix_sum

def count_ones_in_subarray(prefix_sum, l, r):
    if l == 0:
        return prefix_sum[r]
    return prefix_sum[r] - prefix_sum[l - 1]
```

Comment: Why did you answer a C question with Python code? And a code-only answer at that.

Comment: Note that in python there is a standard library function for prefix sum; you don't need to write it yourself: [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).